# intro.js highlighting then going black on LG android device

Tags: javascript, intro.js

We have been using intro.js for a cordova application. It works flawlessly on most of the devices we compiled to but with this specific device (LG optimus L9, which has 4.0.4) the highlighted area shows for just a fraction of a second and then it all goes back to our black overlay.

I have tried touching up the z-index of the higlighted elements in the css but no luck there.
Is there any suggestion to fix this?

Thanks!!!